# In Wordpress is there a way to add annotations/directional markings to a Wysiwyg field?

Tags: annotations, wordpress, wysiwyg, advanced-custom-fields

I'm currently working on a Wordpress site and I need to add annotations and directional markings to some wysiwyg fields I've set up using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

In each of the fields currently I just have some text and an image but I need to add bubbles or comment boxes on top that describe what's going on in the image. Ideally I would like a box I can add a little comment in and an arrow to specify the area I'm talking about.

For reference here's an image of the sort of thing that I need.

[image]

(Ignore the actual content I just Googled annotations but what's being used here is exactly what I need).

Is there another plugin that can do this possibly?

All suggestions are welcome but I'd like to keep the solution as simple as possible, if at all possible because I will eventually need to hand the site over to a client that will be entering the content themselves going forward.